# Update with default values in case clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a single table like

```
CREATE TABLE Mytable (ID int identity, Name nvarchar(10)); 
GO 
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) VALUES ('test1'); 
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) VALUES ('test2'); 
GO 
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Name DEFAULT('test') FOR Name;
```

Now I want to update my Name column like this:

```
Update MyTable
set name = case ID when 1 then DEFAULT END;
```

But I am getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'

How can I use `UPDATE` with `DEFAULT` statement in the `CASE` clause?

Comment: You have an answer now so you know why this doesn't work. But if it worked, are you sure you wanted to update **all the rows of the table**? And put `NULL` in all the rows (except for the one with `id=1` which would get the default value)? Did you really want that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.

The relevant bit of the [grammar for update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) is

```
SET column_name = { expression | default | null }
```

You can only use the `default` keyword in place of an expression, not *inside* an expression. So you would either need to just use the value of the default directly (could be looked up from [the system views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173758.aspx) to be dynamic) or spilt it into two update statements with appropriate mutually exclusive `where` clauses - one using `default` and the second using an expression - if you *really* want to use that keyword.

Comment: If this was in a script or stored procedure, you could also save that default value into a variable and use that in the `CASE` statement.